# Usb4java library, error while claiming an interface on windows machine

Tags: java, usb, libusb

Using libusb and usb4java I am trying to communicate with a USB device. Below is the code with which I am trying to communicate with the USB device on Windows.

***Code Snippet:***

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.usb4java.Context;
import org.usb4java.Device;
import org.usb4java.DeviceDescriptor;
import org.usb4java.DeviceHandle;
import org.usb4java.DeviceList;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;
import org.usb4java.LibUsbException;

public class USBTest {
    public static int VENDOR_ID = 0x0c45;
    public static int PRODUCT_ID = 0x7406;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Device usbDevice = getUsbDevice();
        final DeviceHandle handle = new DeviceHandle();
        int result = LibUsb.open(usbDevice, handle);
        if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to open USB device", result);
        }

        result = LibUsb.claimInterface(handle, 0);
        if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("", result);
        }
        try {
            ByteBuffer data = convertArrayToBuffer(new byte[] {(byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0xF4});
            result = LibUsb.controlTransfer(handle, (byte) 0x09, (byte) (2 << 8 | 9), (short) 0, (short) 0, data, 1000);
            if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to claim interface", result);
            }
            data = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
            final IntBuffer in = IntBuffer.allocate(8);
            result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, (byte) 0, data, in, 1000);
            if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to claim interface", result);
            }
        } catch(final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            result = LibUsb.releaseInterface(handle, 0);
            if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to release interface", result);
            }
        }
    }

    private static ByteBuffer convertArrayToBuffer(final byte[] data) {
        final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        byteBuffer.put(data);
        byteBuffer.position(0);
        return byteBuffer;
    }

    private static Device getUsbDevice() {
        Device usbDevice = null;
        final Context context = new Context();
        int result = LibUsb.init(context);
        if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize the usb device", result);
        }
        final DeviceList deviceList = new DeviceList();
        result = LibUsb.getDeviceList(null, deviceList);
        if(result < 0) {
            throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device list", result);
        }
        for(final Device device : deviceList) {
            final DeviceDescriptor deviceDescriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
            result = LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, deviceDescriptor);
            if(result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
                throw new LibUsbException("Unable to get device descriptor : ", result);
            }
            if(deviceDescriptor.idProduct() == PRODUCT_ID && deviceDescriptor.idVendor() == VENDOR_ID) {
                System.out.println("Product id and vendor id was matched");
                usbDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
        return usbDevice;
    }
}
```

***Error:***

```
Exception in thread "main" org.usb4java.LibUsbException: USB error 3: : Access denied (insufficient permissions)
    at com.usb.device.USBTest.main(USBTest.java:30)
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What backend do you use for the driver?

Comment: Currently I am using libusb drivers to communicate.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

Some further questions: In which line does the error occur (LibUsb.controlTransfer or)? Have you tried setting a configuration? Has the device maybe different interfaces to claim?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help, especially after all this time, but I ran into the same problem and solved it as follows:

First, the device I was working with is a Continua Health Device following the PHDC standard. There is no standard driver for it. I have a driver based upon libusb-win32. The usb4java that I have uses libusbK and that was the problem. I downloaded [Zadig http://zadig.akeo.ie/](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) and replaced the libusb-win32 with the libusbK driver and I no longer got a 'cant claim interface insufficient permission' error.

There is probably a way to use the libusb-win32 driver with usb4java but I did not try that approach. I was just happy to get something to work!

I am still unable to get plug-in events however which kind of stinks.